# How to find top 3 topper of each subject in given table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  - Name - Subject -  Marks
1   - ABC  - MAT    -  90
2   - ABC  - SCI    -  80
3   - ABC  - ENG    -  90
4   - ABC  - HIS    -  96
5   - ABC  - PHY    -  70
6   - ABC  - CHE    -  43
7   - XYZ  - MAT    -  90
8   - XYZ  - SCI    -  80
9   - XYZ  - ENG    -  90
10  - XYZ  - HIS    -  96
11  - XYZ  - PHY    -  70
13  - XYZ  - CHE    -  43

etc .....
```

Just want to show 3 topper  of each subject

```
ABC - MATH - 90
XYZ - MATH - 90
DEF - MATH - 80
etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using variables.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = subject, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := subject, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @s := '') params
      order by subject, marks desc
     ) t 
where rn <= 3
order by t.subject, t.rn;
```

Comment: You should be awarded the omnipresent badge.

Comment: very impressive answer

Comment: i just want add reference to code 

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

With your data I create a <kbd>**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ad77a/4)**.</kbd>

I include two addtional student so query return only 3 from 4.

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
    (`id` int, `Name` varchar(3), `Subject` varchar(3), `Marks` int);
```

And create this derivated to simplify the next code. The idea is create an unique code with 3 number `000-100` + `Name` so I can sorted during `left outer join` using `AND L.comb <= R.comb`.

Take note because this sorting in case of tie the latest name alphabetic will be showing first.

```
CREATE TABLE s_course AS 
    SELECT `id`, `Name`, `Subject`, `Marks`, concat(LPAD(`Marks`, 3, '0'), `Name`) as comb
    FROM Courses;
```

Now the `SELECT`, if you run the inner select will see the 4 result and check how the ties are resolve.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT L.Subject, L.Marks, L.Name, count(*) as rn
      FROM   s_course L
      left outer join s_course R
                   ON L.Subject = R.Subject                  
                  AND L.comb <= R.comb
      GROUP BY L.Subject, L.comb   
      ORDER BY L.Subject, L.comb     
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY Subject, rn
```

OR maybe you can `ORDER BY Subject, Marks DESC, Name`

This query exploit one issue of MySQL where you dont need put the same fields on `select`  and `group by`

**OUTPUT**

```
| Subject | Marks | Name | rn |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     CHE |    48 |  PQR |  1 |
|     CHE |    48 |  FGH |  2 |
|     CHE |    43 |  XYZ |  3 |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     ENG |    95 |  PQR |  1 |
|     ENG |    92 |  FGH |  2 |
|     ENG |    90 |  XYZ |  3 |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     HIS |    96 |  XYZ |  1 |
|     HIS |    96 |  ACB |  2 |
|     HIS |    91 |  PQR |  3 |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     MAT |    95 |  PQR |  1 |
|     MAT |    95 |  FGH |  2 |
|     MAT |    90 |  XYZ |  3 |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     PHY |    75 |  PQR |  1 |
|     PHY |    70 |  XYZ |  2 |
|     PHY |    70 |  ACB |  3 |
|---------|-------|------|----|
|     SCI |    80 |  XYZ |  1 |
|     SCI |    80 |  ACB |  2 |
|     SCI |    75 |  PQR |  3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m1.id, max(m1.marks) 'marks', max(m1.subject) 'subject'
from      marks m1 
left join marks m2 on m2.subject =m1.subject and ( m2.marks>=m1.marks )
left join marks m3 on (m3.subject =m2.subject) and m3.id<>m1.id and m3.id<>m2.id and m3.marks>=m2.marks
left join marks m4 on (m4.subject =m3.subject) and m4.id<>m1.Id and m4.id<>m2.id and m4.id <>m3.id and m4.marks>=m3.marks
left join marks m12 on (m12.subject =m1.subject and m12.subject =m2.subject ) and m12.marks>m1.marks and m12.marks<m2.marks 
left join marks m23 on (m23.subject=m2.subject and m23.subject=m3.subject) and ( m23.marks>m2.marks and m23.marks < m3.marks)
where 
    (m4.id is null)
and m12.id is null
and m23.id is null
group by m1.id
order by max(m1.subject) asc, max(m1.marks) desc
```