# How sort by new date first then by passed date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have date column in mysql database. I need to sort ASC by date, but show dates first that are not happened yet, then witch are happened. How to do that sql statement? Example of results:

```
for date 25 October 2015
new by ASC:
2015-10-25
2015-10-27
2015-11-03
...
then old by DESC:
2015-10-24
2015-10-14
2015-09-10
...
```

ps I am using Yii2 framework (but clean php would be good too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`date` date)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`date`)
VALUES
    ('2015-10-25'),
    ('2015-10-27'),
    ('2015-11-03'),
    ('2015-10-24'),
    ('2015-10-14'),
    ('2015-09-10')
;
```

and this query:

```
SELECT
date
FROM
t
ORDER BY
date >= CURDATE() DESC
, ABS(DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE()));
```

You get the output you want:

```
|                        date |
|-----------------------------|
|   October, 25 2015 00:00:00 |
|   October, 27 2015 00:00:00 |
|  November, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
|   October, 24 2015 00:00:00 |
|   October, 14 2015 00:00:00 |
| September, 10 2015 00:00:00 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0aa1d/11/0)

Comment: Clever use of `abs(datediff())` for this purpose.  Note that this works for dates, but if there were a time component the logic would be a bit trickier.

Comment: Hi there @GordonLinoff my answer was based using your previous answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282377/how-to-find-top-3-topper-of-each-subject-in-given-table let me know if there is a compact way to do the same

Answer (score 0):

I fell silly after check fancyPants solution.

But I want show the one I was working with

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccf6f/36)**

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*,
               (@rn := if(true, @rn + 1, 1)
               ) as rn
        FROM myTable t         
        CROSS JOIN
              (select @rn := 0) params
        WHERE dateField >= NOW()
        ORDER BY dateField asc
      ) X
  UNION 
  SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*,
                 (@bn := if(true, @bn + 1, 1)
                 ) as rn
        FROM myTable t         
        CROSS JOIN
              (select @bn := (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM myTable 
                              WHERE dateField >= NOW()
                             ) a
              ) params
        WHERE dateField < NOW()
        ORDER BY dateField desc
      ) Y
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|                   dateField | rn |
|-----------------------------|----|
|   October, 25 2015 00:00:00 |  1 |
|   October, 27 2015 00:00:00 |  2 |
|  November, 03 2015 00:00:00 |  3 |
|   October, 24 2015 00:00:00 |  4 |
|   October, 14 2015 00:00:00 |  5 |
| September, 10 2015 00:00:00 |  6 |
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, but it is an interesting interpretation.